# Swift calling static methods: type(of: self) vs explicit class name

Tags: swift, static-methods

In swift, an instance `func` can't call a `static/class func` without prefixing the method call with the class name. OR you can use `type(of: self)`, e.g

```
class Foo {
    static func doIt() { }

    func callIt() {
        Foo.doIt() // This works
        type(of: self).doIt() // Or this

        doIt() // This doesn't compile (unresolved identifier)
    }
}
```

My question is, what's the difference here?
Is it just a matter of coding style, or is there some difference e.g. static or dynamic dispatch going on?

If it is just coding style, what's the preferred style?

Comment: I don't believe there is any dynamic dispatch.  We're not in Objective-C world since there's no `@objc`, `dynamic`, or `NSObject` inheritance.

Comment: @JAL Actually [Swift class *are* Obj-C classes](https://mikeash.com/pyblog/friday-qa-2014-07-18-exploring-swift-memory-layout.html) under the hood (at least when the Obj-C runtime is included). And 'pure' Swift does have dynamic dispatch too (think protocols) – it's not just an Obj-C thing.

Comment: @Hamish I know that Swift classes inherit from SwiftObject, but does the same apply with the open source runtime (excluding protocols)?

Comment: @JAL Yeah, I was just about to edit my comment to note that – I haven't looked at the open source runtime in much detail, but I don't *believe* Swift classes are based on Obj-C classes there, as there's no Obj-C runtime.

Comment: Follow this proposal for apple's thoughts on this: https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0068-universal-self.md

Comment: Another option: `Self.doIt()`. Using `Self` (big S) lets you reference a static member from an instance member. It's less verbose than using `type(of: self)` and it avoids needing to type out the actual class name, such as `Foo`.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

There are two main differences.

#### 1. The value of `self` inside the static method

The metatype that you call the static method on is available to you in the method as `self` (it's simply passed as an implicit parameter). Therefore if you call `doIt()` on [`type(of: self)`](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Expressions.html#//apple_ref/swift/grammar/postfix-self-expression), `self` will be the *dynamic* metatype of the instance. If you call it on `Foo`, `self` will be `Foo.self`.

```
class Foo {
    static func doIt() {
        print("hey I'm of type \(self)")
    }

    func callDoItOnDynamicType() {
        type(of: self).doIt() // call on the dynamic metatype of the instance.
    }

    func classDoItOnFoo() {
        Foo.doIt() // call on the metatype Foo.self.
    }
}

class Bar : Foo {}

let f: Foo = Bar()

f.callDoItOnDynamicType() // hey I'm of type Bar
f.classDoItOnFoo()        // hey I'm of type Foo
```

This difference can be *really* important for factory methods, as it determines the type of instance you create.

```
class Foo {
    required init() {}

    static func create() -> Self {
        return self.init()
    }

    func createDynamic() -> Foo {
        return type(of: self).create()
    }

    func createFoo() -> Foo {
        return Foo.create()
    }
}

class Bar : Foo {}

let f: Foo = Bar()

print(f.createDynamic()) // Bar
print(f.createFoo())     // Foo
```

#### 2. The dispatching of the static method

(*[Martin has already covered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42260517/2976878) this, but I thought I would add it for the sake of completion.*)

For `class` methods that are overridden in subclasses, the value of the metatype that you call the method on determines which implementation to call.

If called on a metatype that is known at compile time (e.g `Foo.doIt()`), Swift is able to statically dispatch the call. However, if you call the method on a metatype that isn't known until runtime (e.g `type(of: self)`), the method call will be *dynamically* dispatched to the correct implementation for the metatype value.

```
class Foo {
    class func doIt() {
        print("Foo's doIt")
    }

    func callDoItOnDynamicType() {
        type(of: self).doIt() // the call to doIt() will be dynamically dispatched.
    }

    func classDoItOnFoo() {
        Foo.doIt() // will be statically dispatched.
    }
}


class Bar : Foo {
    override class func doIt() {
        print("Bar's doIt")
    }
}

let f: Foo = Bar()

f.callDoItOnDynamicType() // Bar's doIt
f.classDoItOnFoo()        // Foo's doIt
```

Answer (score 4):

For a `class` method it makes a difference if the method is
overridden in a subclass:

```
class Foo {
    class func doIt() {
        print("Foo doit")
    }

    func callViaClassname() {
        Foo.doIt()
    }

    func callViaTypeOf() {
        type(of: self).doIt()
    }
}

class Bar: Foo {
    override class func doIt() {
        print("Bar doit")
    }

}

Bar().callViaClassname() // Foo doit
Bar().callViaTypeOf() // Bar doit
```

This is also documented in ["Types"](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Types.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH31-ID445) in the Swift Language Reference:

> You can use a `type(of:)` expression with an instance of a type to access that instance’s dynamic, runtime type as a value, ...

<strike>I don't know a difference for a `static` method (which is `final`
and cannot be overridden in a subclass).</strike>
*Correction:* See [Hamish's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42260880/1187415) for the difference 
in both static and class methods.

Comment: The difference for both `static` and `class` methods is the value of `self` inside the method – see my answer :)

Comment: @Hamish: Yes, that is a good point, and I had not thought about that.