# Refer to 'self' in a static context

Tags: ios, swift, class

I'm here to understand why the solution I had implemented won't work. Basically I have a class called `MyClass` and in this class I'd like to have a static dictionary created from a plist file. Like this:

```
class MyClass {        
    static var myDic: [String: String] = NSDictionary(contentsOfFile: Bundle(for: self).path(forResource: "filename", ofType: "plist")!) as! [String: String]    
}
```

If I do so, compiler will complain that:

```
Cannot convert value of type '(MyClass) -> () -> (MyClass)' to expected argument type 'AnyClass' (aka 'AnyObject.Type')
```

But if I change `myDic` var and create a static method returning that dic, all is fine:

```
class MyClass {
    static func myDic() -> [String: String] {
        return NSDictionary(contentsOfFile: Bundle(for: self).path(forResource: "PlayerRolesWithColors", ofType: "plist")!) as! [String: String]
    }
}
```

Two questions here:

1. What does this sintax mean in the compiler error? `'(MyClass) -> () -> (MyClass)'`
2. What's the difference between the two cases? Why doesn't the former work and the latter is fine?

Thanks.

Comment: Good questions, worth answering :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets look at a simpler (working) example keeping your core issue the same:

```
class ClassName {
    static var bundle = Bundle(for: ClassName.self)
    
    static func getBundle() -> Bundle {
        return Bundle(for: self)
    }
}
```

Firstly, lets note that `Bundle(for: AnyClass)` takes an object type.

---

### 1. Regarding Variables

Variables at top-level, access `self` as `ClassName` which is an instance type, whether it is declared as `let`/`var`/`lazy`/computed, static or not.

So:

```
static var bundle = Bundle(for: self)
```

is same as:

```
static var bundle = Bundle(for: ClassName())
```

Both are invalid and generate the following error:

> Cannot convert value of type 'ClassName' to expected argument type 'AnyClass' (aka 'AnyObject.Type')

For sure, this is because we're passing an instance type instead of the expected Object type.

#### Solution:

```
static var bundle = Bundle(for: ClassName.self)
```

---

### 2. Regarding static functions

As for a static function, this is a bit different.

> The metatype that you call the static method on is available to you in the method as `self` (it's simply passed as an implicit parameter).
>
> <sub>*Ref: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42260880/2857130*</sub>

In my example, we have:

```
static func getBundle() -> Bundle {
    return Bundle(for: self)
}
```

When you call `ClassName.getBundle()`, `ClassName.Type` is implicitly passed to the function.
Now within the static function, `self` is of type `ClassName.Type` which is an Object type and can be applied directly in `Bundle(for:)`, or similar functions that accept an Object type as it's parameter.

So, static functions access `self` as `ClassName.Type` which is same as `ClassName.self`, just not apparent as it's passed implicitly.

You can confirm this behavior of `self` in a `static` function, and furthermore even observe how `self` behaves in a normal function in the following example:

```
class ClassName {
    static func check() {
        print("static function check")
        print(type(of: self)) //ClassName.Type
        //same as
        print(type(of: ClassName.self)) //ClassName.Type
        
        //test
        print(type(of: self) == type(of: ClassName.self)) //true
    }
    
    func check() {
        print("normal function check")
        print(type(of: self)) //ClassName
        
        //test
        print(type(of: self) == type(of: ClassName.self)) //false
    }
}

ClassName.check()
ClassName().check()
```

Also shows us that normal functions access `self` as `ClassName` which is an instance type, similar to variables.

---

### Summary:

- `Bundle(for:)` takes an object type
- Variables at top-level, access `self` as `ClassName` which is an instance type
- Normal functions access `self` as `ClassName` which is an instance type
- Static functions access `self` as `ClassName.Type` which is an Object type, as it's passed implicitly to the function

Comment: Note there is a big difference between `static` functions and `class` functions.

Comment: @Sulthan Sure, there must be (and we haven't spoken of `class` functions) but... in the context of his question, it still wouldn't matter if that were a `static func` or `class func` as `type(of: self)` in both cases would still be `ClassName.Type`.

Comment: Not in a subclass but you are right that's probably out of scope for this question.

Answer (score 1):

You can do

```
class MyClass {
    static var myDic: [String: String] = NSDictionary(contentsOfFile: Bundle(for:MyClass.self).path(forResource: "filename", ofType: "plist")!) as! [String: String]
}
```

As you can't access `self` inside a static variable , or use the bundle identifier

```
class MyClass {
    static var myDic: [String: String] = NSDictionary(contentsOfFile: Bundle(identifier: "comThisBundle")!.path(forResource: "filename", ofType: "plist")!) as! [String: String]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use the class name instead of `self`.

You also shouldn't be using `NSDictionary` and then casting to a Swift `Dictionary`. Use `PropertyListDecoder` instead.

```
class MyClass {
    static let myDic = try! PropertyListDecoder().decode([String:String].self, from: try! Data(contentsOf: Bundle(for: MyClass.self).url(forResource: "filename", withExtension: "plist")))
}
```

Comment: Which is unfortunately a very poor solution (even if other solutions are currently impossible). I am still waiting for https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0068-universal-self.md to be implemented.

Comment: @Sulthan yes, for generic methods, this workaround is not suitable and that proposal would be great to have implemented

Comment: @DávidPásztor Thanks for pointing me to the PropertyListDecoder I didn't know.